Unable to get OAuth2.0 get access token
I get the below error:

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS9002313: Invalid
request. Request is malformed or invalid. Trace ID:
68670f14-0eff-403c-9681-f99d5d3d5700 Correlation ID:
0f112149-c7fb-410a-b08e-6db049f63751 Timestamp: 2024-05-28
07:20:28Z","error_codes":[9002313],"timestamp":"2024-05-28
07:20:28Z","trace_id":"68670f14-0eff-403c-9681-f99d5d3d5700","correlation_id":"0f112149-c7fb-410a-b08e-6db049f63751","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"}

Here is my current code:**

`
TokenResponse token = null;
            string tokenEndPoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9fa257f-...c3/oauth2/token";

            string clientId = Common.ConfigWrapper.Get("OAuthClientID", "");
            string clientSecret = Common.ConfigWrapper.Get("OAuthclientSecret", "");
            string redirectUri = Common.ConfigWrapper.Get("OAuthRedirectUri", "");

            string encodedRedirectUri = Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUri);

            // Set the request valuers.
            var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", redirectUri)
            };
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

                using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenEndPoint, content))
                {
                    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseString);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Optionally log or handle the error response
                        var errorResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseString);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {errorResponse["error"]}, Description: {errorResponse["error_description"]}");
                    }
                }
            }

            return token;
`


**Here is one of the 10 000 other wys of trying to get some type of positive result back:
In postman, I got it to work using the below, I think postman probably adds other headers which makes the post successfull, but I can't which if there are any. Any advise or help to what I am doing wrong/missing, I have been struggling for two days now.
**
`
string tokenEndPoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9fa27...4c3/oauth2/token";
string clientId = Common.ConfigWrapper.Get("OAuthClientID", "");
string clientSecret = Common.ConfigWrapper.Get("OAuthclientSecret", "");
string redirectUri = Common.ConfigWrapper.Get("OAuthRedirectUri", "");

string encodedRedirectUri = Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUri);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
        // Add headers explicitly
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache");

        var requestBody = new StringContent("{ \"key\": \"value\" }", Encoding.UTF8"application/json");

        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", $"{code}"),
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", $"{encodedRedirectUri}"),
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", $"{clientId}"),
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", $"{clientSecret}")
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        var response = client.PostAsync(tokenEndPoint,
              new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>() 
               {
                   { "client_id", clientId},
                   { "scope", "123"},
                   { "redirect_uri", encodedRedirectUri },
                   { "refresh_token", code},
                   { "grant_type", "refresh_token" },
                   { "client_secret", clientSecret }
                })).Result;

         var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

         if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
              responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

              Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode}");
              Console.WriteLine($"Response: {responseContent}");

              Logr.LogINF("MFA Login failed :" + responseContent);
              var error = $"Token request failed. Status Code: {response.StatusCode}.";

              return error;
          }

         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

         var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

         var tokenReponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseString);

         return tokenReponse;
   }``


To generate the auth-code, use the below endpoint:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=RedirectURL
&response_mode=query
&scope=offline_access User.Read 
&state=12345


Modify the code to generate access and refresh tokens and to refresh the access token:
namespace OAuthExample
{
    public class TokenResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("token_type")]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
        public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
        public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    }

    public class OAuthClient
    {
        private string clientId = "ClientID";
        private string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
        private string redirectUri = "https://jwt.ms";
        private string tokenEndPoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token";

        public async Task<TokenResponse> GetTokenAsync(string code)
        {
            TokenResponse token = null;

            var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", redirectUri)
            };

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

                using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenEndPoint, content))
                {
                    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseString);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var errorResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseString);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {errorResponse["error"]}, Description: {errorResponse["error_description"]}");
                    }
                }
            }

            return token;
        }

        public async Task<TokenResponse> RefreshTokenAsync(string refreshToken)
        {
            TokenResponse token = null;

            var postData = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "client_id", clientId },
                { "scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" },
                { "redirect_uri", redirectUri },
                { "refresh_token", refreshToken },
                { "grant_type", "refresh_token" },
                { "client_secret", clientSecret }
            };

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

                using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenEndPoint, content))
                {
                    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Response: {responseString}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseString);
                    }
                }
            }

            return token;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string authorizationCode = "auth-code-here"; 

            var oauthClient = new OAuthClient();
            TokenResponse token = await oauthClient.GetTokenAsync(authorizationCode);

            if (token != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {token.AccessToken}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Token Type: {token.TokenType}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Expires In: {token.ExpiresIn}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Refresh Token: {token.RefreshToken}");

                TokenResponse refreshedToken = await oauthClient.RefreshTokenAsync(token.RefreshToken);

                if (refreshedToken != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Refreshed Token:");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {refreshedToken.AccessToken}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Token Type: {refreshedToken.TokenType}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Expires In: {refreshedToken.ExpiresIn}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Refresh Token: {refreshedToken.RefreshToken}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to refresh token.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to obtain token.");
            }
        }
    }
}



The access and refresh token and refreshed access and refresh token got generated successfully:


Thank you very much I got it to work. I released the package to the staging environment but I now get the below error, I am not sure what it means. (Sorry I am new to OAuth). It is a new login why does it close the connection?
Error Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
It happens at the below line of code:
HttpResponseMessage tokenReponse = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndPoint, tokenRequest);
Locally it works 100%, obviously the staging environment has it's own Oauth Endpoints and tenantId's etc.
